# Dice throws - show that expected values are equal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, dice

> We throw a six-sided die independently.
>
> Let be $X_1$ a random variable (rv) that counts all throws until we see the the first time two consecutive $6$'s. Let be $X_2$ the rv that ignores the first throw and counts all throws from the second throw until the first time we see two consecutive $6$'s.
>
> Show that the expected values $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_2)$ are equal. (Hint: assume that those expected values exist.)

---

Is it possible to answer this question without using any advanced concepts of measure or probability theory?

Intuitively this statement makes sense. But maybe there is some basic argument I can use to back up my intuition.

**My approach:**

Let be $\omega$ some element that represents a sequence of dice throws and we assume that $X(\omega)=k$. Though, we don't know how the sample space or the probability measure look like it makes sense that we can identify each sequence of dice throws by $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots)$ and due to the independence of the individual throws the probability measure should satisfy $P((\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots))=p(\omega_1)p(\omega_2)p(\omega_3)\cdots$. Further $\{X=k\}$ represents a set consisting of $\omega$'s where the first two consecutive $6$'s appear at throw $(k-1)$ and $k$.

Now, we simply add another element $\omega_0$ at the beginning of each of those sequences $\omega\in\{X=k\}$, e.g. $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots)$ produces six new sequences like $(1,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots)$,  $(2,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots)$, $(3,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots)$ etc. As the individual entries $\omega_i$ are independent by assumption this new set, we call it $M$, has the same probability as $\{X=k\}$. By construction all $\omega\in M$ satisfy $X_2(\omega)=k$. Of course we can do it the other way around if we start with  the set $\{X_2=k\}$ and cut off the first entry. So we see that $P(\{X_1=k\})=P(\{X_2=k\})$ and as a result both expected values must attain the same value.

---

Is this a valid reasoning? Maybe someone has another good idea?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you looking at a single string of tosses or a different one for each variable?  If different ones, then these are identically distributed.  If the same one, they aren't.

Comment: @lulu, what do you mean by single string? I am looking at a set of strings/sequences.

Comment: It seems intuitively obvious that the two random variables have the same distribution and so the same expectation.  Both are "throw $k-1$ dice and ignore their results and then, starting from the $k$th throw, count how many throws it takes to see two consecutive $6$s", with $k=1$ for $X_1$ and $k=2$ for $X_2$.  Clearly the warm-up throws are irrelevant for the distributions since you are going to ignore them.